# Item Promote from "Master" to "Internet" failed. - Error: "Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

We are using `Sitecore 9.1` (Initial release) and `Publishing Service (4.0)`. Suddenly publishing service started throwing errors:

```
2022-05-04 01:00:31.327 +00:00 [Error] Item Promote from "Master" to "Internet" failed. - Error: "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
2022-05-04 01:00:31.342 +00:00 [Error] An error occured running an operation on Manifest 8933c141-119c-4d37-ab25-45beb1c1488a, sourceStore "Internet". - Error: "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
2022-05-04 01:00:31.342 +00:00 [Error] One or more targets were not succesfully promoted.
System.AggregateException: One or more targets were not succesfully promoted.  The failed target(s) are: Manifest=8933c141-119c-4d37-ab25-45beb1c1488a Target=8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254.
 See inner exceptions for details. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.<ReadBufferedAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.<ReadBufferedAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<GetChangeReport>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<AddOrUpdateVariants>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`1.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<ExecuteAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseConnection`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<AddOrUpdateVariants>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.ClassicItemRepository.<SaveVariants>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ItemManifestPromoteWorker.<SaveVariants>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<Promote>b__4>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ManifestPromoterBase.<ProcessManifestInBatches>d__4`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<Promote>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ManifestPromoterBase.<Promote>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<Promote>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<RunAndLogPromote>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<RunAndLogPromote>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass9_3.<<PromoteAll>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<RunAllOperationsInParallel>d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.<ReadBufferedAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.<ReadBufferedAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<GetChangeReport>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<AddOrUpdateVariants>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`1.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<ExecuteAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseConnection`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<AddOrUpdateVariants>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.ClassicItemRepository.<SaveVariants>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ItemManifestPromoteWorker.<SaveVariants>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<Promote>b__4>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ManifestPromoterBase.<ProcessManifestInBatches>d__4`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<Promote>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ManifestPromoterBase.<Promote>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<Promote>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<RunAndLogPromote>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<RunAndLogPromote>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass9_3.<<PromoteAll>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<RunAllOperationsInParallel>d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.<ReadBufferedAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.<ReadBufferedAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<GetChangeReport>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<AddOrUpdateVariants>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`1.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<ExecuteAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseConnection`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.SqlServer.ClassicSqlServerDataProvider.<AddOrUpdateVariants>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Classic.ClassicItemRepository.<SaveVariants>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ItemManifestPromoteWorker.<SaveVariants>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<Promote>b__4>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ManifestPromoterBase.<ProcessManifestInBatches>d__4`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<Promote>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.ManifestPromoterBase.<Promote>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultItemManifestPromoter.<Promote>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<RunAndLogPromote>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<RunAndLogPromote>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.DefaultPromotionCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass9_3.<<PromoteAll>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.DataPromotion.NonTransactionalOperationStrategy.<RunAllOperationsInParallel>d__4.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:b10abffe-4223-4b89-8bf1-b3d3ad77525a
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
ClientConnectionId before routing:f74db522-040a-48d5-a464-8238a1c58e14
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned this happens on larger publish tasks and given the error message this sounds like a timeout issue. I've found this to be a common issue with SPS when working with large data sets.

Try increasing the timeouts configured in `/config/sitecore/publishing/sc.publishing.xml`. Also ensure `<TransactionalPromote>` is turned off. Otherwise large publish sets may cause all sorts of strange issues, such as running out of temp storage, locking issues etc.

It's also worth looking into the database indexes, the Links database indexes in particular. If they are very fragmented, publish operations may take longer time.

Though probably not related to this specific issue, it may be worth looking into the SPS cleanup tasks as well (`sc.publishing.tasks.xml`). Run those more often (`Interval` setting) than default and keep a jobs for a shorter time period (`JobAge` parameter). I've found this to be needed in most setups, as the SPS support tables grow really large, making operations heavier and may cause timeouts. Open the SPS publishing dashboard and click "Recent jobs". If that page takes a long time to load, it's a good indication of this issue.

Comment: Publishing_TargetSyncState table had issue, so manually cleanup is required to do. Thanks for you inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As per your error logs, I think you are getting some issues connecting with your `SQL Server`.

It looks like the Permission issue with `SQL Server` with the User-defined per database in the connection string.

Try to update your `connection string` and use your `SQL` admin user, not the database user which is created during installation.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: No, that is not the issue. For normal publishing, there is no problem. When do full publish or item has thousands of children then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it clearly is a SQL server timeout. If the publishing works for single item or subset of items it could be they are already up to date and not being published again. Try to do a republish on a single item to confirm if the issue is with specific item or all items.

Because the issue seems to be with SQL server timeouts I suspect there might be locks and blocks on the database tables. If you have access to the database check for blocked processes. Here is a good article on how to check for blocks and resolve them on SQL server

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2429/how-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/